# Issue with indexing transient fields in Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, search, lucene, hibernate-search

I was trying to create a Lucene indexed document containing embeddables, collections as well as transient variable. I can see the embedded as well as collection variables in the document when I open it with Apache Luke however i am not able to find the transient fields. Any help or suggestions shall be highly appreciated.

Comment: If null value is possible, make sure you specify indexNullAs = "_null_" or some value to ensure value is always there. Also  Make sure you manually index/re-index once so that it can pickup existing values.

Comment: Also, make sure its being picked up by auto-index. If nothing changed in the object, hibernate will not pickup the change. It look for dirty flag. If that is the case, you have to set the dirty flag to false (default is true) in the configuration.

Comment: in case of auto-index when the transient field updated, make sure the indexing happens in the same session of updating the domain, as FullTextSessionImpl#index() requires it: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/orm/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/impl/FullTextSessionImpl.java#L135-L157

Answer (score 0):

i tried to use an @IndexedEmbedded annotation along with depth and includePath property set but that doesnt work. In some other forum it is mentioned transient variables get autoIndexed so i tried to write a hibernate search query inside a Junit test case but it fails with the SearchException thrown( field not found in the index). The search query as a Junit test for other fields seem to work fine though.

Even When i open the indexed document with Apache luke i am unable to find the transient field. So its evident the particular field is not being indexed.

Rest of the other fields which are either within embeddables or within collections are being indexed properly.